# How to resolve "Your app or its metadata still appears to contain misleading content."

Tags: swift3, io, app-store, apple-developer

At Present, I am facing this Problem.

when I uploaded to the App store after some hours my app had got rejected.
Error Which is showing By the App store.

our app or its metadata still appears to contain misleading content.
Specifically, your app includes content that resembles Deepak Sinde without the necessary authorization.

Next Steps

You may attach documentary evidence in the App Review Information section in App Store Connect. In accordance with section 3.2(f) of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement, you acknowledge that submitting falsified or fraudulent documentation can result in the termination of your Apple Developer Program account and the removal of your apps from the App Store. Once Legal has reviewed your documentation and confirms its validity, we will proceed with the review of your app.

Alternatively, please remove the third-party content from your app and its metadata.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined by the [help]. If you have a question about Apple product policies, you should reach out to their customer service representatives, instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any use of public names, brands which you have inside your app or metadata must be agreed by them. In my case I was working for an application for Dunlop. First time I got app rejected. After providing to Apple official papers with express confirmation of use of Dunlop brand, signed by brand's official representative, app got approved without issues.